# Scenario on Selecting Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

I have a scenario to fetch few records out of multiple records in database.
Source records below pertains to One account holder.

```
PrimaryOrSecondary  Duplicate_Account_ID    Account_ID  START_DATE  END_DATE
------------------  --------------------  ------------  ----------  --------
Primary     1000    1000    26/05/2017    NULL

Primary     1000    1000    10/03/2014    25/05/2017

Secondary   2000    1000    26/05/2017    NULL

Secondary   3000    1000    10/03/2014    25/05/2017
```

Out of these 4 records I have to apply below rules to get only one target record.

1. If Duplicate_Account_ID=Account_ID(then it is PRIMARY record) and if its END_DATE IS NULL then populate that record in target and look no further.
2. If END_DATE IS NULL in Step 1 , then go to Secondary record where Duplicate_Account_ID<>Account_ID and see if any record has NULL END_DATE. If found then populate that record in target.
3. If no records found in Step 2, then go back to Primary record and get the record that has the Maximum START_DATE and populate that record in target.

Ultimately I need one record in target table from these 4 records in source.

Any help pls.

Comment: What do you mean by "populate that record"? update it with something? It's not clear what you are asking. What should the values in the table look like after the update?

Comment: pls see updated. thx.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? MYSQL?

Comment: SQL Server. thx.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't tagged your DBMS but here is the SQL Server solution

```
INSERT  INTO yourothertable
SELECT  TOP 1
        PrimaryOrSecondary,
        Duplicate_Account_ID,
        Account_ID,
        START_DATE,
        END_DATE
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    MAX(START_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY PrimaryOrSecondary) AS MaxDate
            FROM    yourtable
        ) a
WHERE   (Duplicate_Account_ID = Account_ID AND END_DATE IS NULL) OR
        (PrimaryOrSecondary = 'Secondary' AND Duplicate_Account_ID<>Account_ID AND END_DATE IS NULL) OR
        (PrimaryOrSecondary = 'Primary' AND MaxDate = START_DATE)
ORDER BY
        CASE
            WHEN Duplicate_Account_ID = Account_ID AND END_DATE IS NULL
            THEN 1
            WHEN PrimaryOrSecondary = 'Secondary' AND Duplicate_Account_ID<>Account_ID AND END_DATE IS NULL
            THEN 2
            WHEN PrimaryOrSecondary = 'Primary' AND MaxDate = START_DATE
            THEN 3
        END
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to add more complexity to this. I have another column called Type in source and it has values like 'Staff' or 'Student', I have to add this to the partition in MAX? And while selecting top 1 I have to consider this Type column also. So to achieve this, I have added  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Account_ID, Type ORDER BY MAXDATE)  as RN. And then select where RN=1. Do you think this will work?

Comment: You need to update your question with your query and what you are trying to achieve. Also, the best way to see if something works is to try it!